# How to recover deleted .zip files through TWRP?

Tags: twrp, restore

I deleted internal storage and forgot that my .zip backups was there. I have no OS installed, only access via TWRP. How can I restore my .zip files?

Comment: make a (decrypted) partition dump and inspect the image with linux tools on pc

Comment: Thanks, found month older backup before you commented. Didn't think that it's so difficult. Just noticed that softwares on Windows doesn't detect my device.